# extract raster values into each polygon in a shapefile in Python

Tags: python, spatial, geopandas, gdal, rasterio

I have a Gtiff layer and a shapefile with 5 polygons that are placed across the Gtiff (both have the same crs). I'm trying to create a NumPy array for each polygon that contains the pixels that are masked by that polygon.
The code I managed to build is attaching the entire raster to each polygon and not just the relevant pixels.
Any suggestions?

```
polygons = gpd.read_file(poly_path.shp)
burn_attribute = "id"  # should be unique for the polygons and not contain zero
with rasterio.open(raster_path.tif") as src:
    raster = src.read(1)


pixel_values = []

for i in range(len(polygons)):
    # Create a mask from the current polygon
    mask = rasterio.features.geometry_mask([polygons.geometry[i]],
                                          out_shape=raster.shape,
                                           transform=src.transform,
                                           all_touched=True,
                                           invert=False)
    # Extract the pixel values within the polygon
    polygon_values = raster[mask]
    # Append the pixel values to the list
    pixel_values.append(polygon_values)

# Add the pixel values as a new column to the polygons GeoDataFrame
polygons['pixel_values'] = pixel_values

extracted_values = raster[polygons]
```

Comment: My suggestion is to look at [rasterstats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/) which is a popular python library that does exactly what you need